# Setting up C++11 (std::thread) for NDK with ADT/Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, c++11, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have been trying to use C++11. I am developing an android project and i want to use std::mutex. Along with OpenCV
But no matter what I do, I just cant seem to fix the `Type 'mutex' could not be resolved`
error.

I have tried following the tutorials i found on SO and other places.
[LINK1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131763/eclipse-cdt-c11-c0x-support) [LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763937/c0x-compiles-but-eclipse-editor-errors-even-with-gnu0x-discovery) [LINK3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564544/build-c0x-features-with-eclipse)[LINK4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312854/eclipse-indexer-cant-resolve-shared-ptr)

1. ADT v22.3.0-887826
2. Installed C/C++ compilers (CDT)

Following so many tutorials, it has become a real mess now. So I will explain my current settings

- Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Tool  Chain Editor

  - Current Tool Chain is "Cross GCC"
  - Current Builder is "Android Builder"
- Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Discovery Options

  - Compiler invocation command is "gcc"
  - Compilter Invocation argments are -E -P -v -dD "${plugin_state_location}/specs.c     -std=c++11"
- Project > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > # Symbols tab

  - Symbol = __cplusplus and Value = 1

In my Application.mk file I have the following

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_USE_CPP0X := true
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

I tried to change the **cplusplus symbol's value to 201103L
and tried __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X** with an empty value

But nothing seems to work, What am I doing wrong??

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the problem simply an error highlighted by Eclipse, or does your build fail as well? Eclipse is buggy with C++11.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android NDK build, Method could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155676/android-ndk-build-method-could-not-be-resolved). Either way, you don't need CDT; you must install NDK though.

Comment: I don't think *"`__cplusplus` and Value = 1"* is correct; the value should be at least `201103L` for C++11 in my opinion. But I think you really shouldn't mess with the value `__cplusplus`. Now, what does *"But nothing seems to work"* mean? In short, please answer Steve's question.

Comment: One more thing: [Did you rebuild the index](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14135232/341970)?

Comment: well thanks for the replies. I have rebuilt the index. I have correct paths to NDK as well. I can build a simple opencv code with native support calling a single c++ function.

Comment: @Steve - the build keeps failing. Does that mean it fails just because  Eclipse is buggy? Is there a work around for this? I find it extremely frustrating. Two days and this problem does not go away

Comment: @Ali as I mentioned, I did change the value from 1 to 201103L. And the same error persists.

Comment: @Wajih Yes, I saw that, I am just saying it was a pointless attempt and perhaps you might as well remove it from the question.

Comment: Well let me check the answer as my question has been marked duplicate.

Comment: I am so out of luck right now! The error is still there after following the answer

Comment: What is the actual version of GCC you're using? If `__cplusplus` == 1, then it's quite likely too old a version.

Comment: The original title was misleading. The real problem had nothing to do with ADT, but rather with NDK.

Comment: If you found the answer, _post it as an answer_.

Comment: If you need to use non-GPL code due to contractual obligations, then see [Issue 216331: STLport does not support C++11](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216331) in the AOSP bug tracker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Support for `std::thread` is a bit special. The issue is addressed, for example, in [this article by Binglong](http://binglongx.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/c11-on-android-ndk-r9c/). The article is really short, but it can be summarized in one sentence:

> You cannot use the (default) gcc 4.6 toolchain if you want to `#include <thread>` or `#include <mutex>`.

So, please add `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.8` or `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang` to your `Application.mk`.

For ADT to rebuild its *Index* correctly, see  *[Android NDK build, Method could not be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155676/android-ndk-build-method-could-not-be-resolved)* or *[Eclipse compiles successfully but still gives semantic errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786555/eclipse-compiles-successfully-but-still-gives-semantic-errors)*.

Comment: So what about the "include" sources where from tutorials I see cxx-stt/4.6 sort of stuff. Does this mean I have to change the include sources too? Probably yes, only then will your answer work, right?

Comment: Let us split your problem in two. First of all, make sure that your **ndk-build** works. Second, work around the Eclipse indexer. For the second step, naturally, you want to substitute `4.6` in *[Android NDK build, Method could not be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155676/android-ndk-build-method-could-not-be-resolved)* by `4.8`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well NDK does build under current settings which includes 4.6 as I am able to use it with OpenCV. So I will check on te 4.8 issue. I guess most people don't mention what needs to be included properly so that c++11 can be fully supported. Will post back once I go through the links you have mentioned.

Comment: Well I have tried the settings now I was able to remove the error finally But still I am not sure if everything will work fine. I declared std::mutex, as I type i wont find the auto-completion feature show me 'mutex' as an option. I assume this is only an indexing problem? Take a look at my settings please do let me know if anything is wrong. http://postimg.org/image/z0j1ehvft/

Comment: No, the trick for the Indexer is to uncheck *compatible only* and choose *Linux GCC* toolchain.

Comment: But still, why would not a cross GCC compiler be good? I saw it as an option in a few posts.

Comment: There are probably different workarounds for the problem with *Indexer*. Maybe your approach is good, too.

Comment: I could not find the "compatible only" option, may be eclipse or my brain is too messed up right now!

Comment: Well reply to me where i can find the indexer option. Till then I am marking yours' as an answer and going to put that image there!

Comment: Yes I have! Finally it has worked! Man was this so tough to nail. I had to restart eclipse, which took me 3 hours to figure out :) But all is working.

Comment: Where is Android.mk in VisualStudio android project?

Comment: @MichaelIvanov as far as I know, MS Visual Studio does not create or use **Android.mk** file. Some while ago, their solution was using a normal NDK project with **Android.mk** under the hood (see https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/) but today *[a bunch of XMLs is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36219677/visual-studio-2015-android-is-missing-mk-files-for-ndk-native-development)*. But why do you care?

Comment: As of 2018-15-01, the link to the Binglong article leads to a wall that states that the article in question is private, thus rendering it unaccessible to pretty much everyone who has not been given privileges by the article's author.

Comment: @Adrien, thanks for letting know. At any rate, I did post the summary of that article. Note that it isn't relevant these days: current NDK r16 supports C++11 and even C++17, but gcc toolchain is going away in the next release. Also, eclipse has been deprecated for many years now.

Answer (score 2):

In **Android.mk** add `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11 -D __cplusplus=201103L` then rebuild your project (for reconfiguring compiler). After rebuilding, your project automatically adds needed stl path into **Path and Symbols**

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade the NDK or install a fresh version of Android Studio (2.1 at time of writing) and have Android Studio download the NDK for you you will get revision 12 - which has a lot of the std:: defines not defined in \ndk-bundle\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.9\libs\armeabi-v7a\include\bits\c++config.h - ones relevant for threading being such as _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS which hides the thread class in "thread" for example.

It says that after revision 10e that gcc is deprecated. And with this all the defines as mentioned - which thoroughly buggered our thread dependant JNI code.

Clang as suggested in other posts is not a solution for us as it amongst other things seems not to support thead_local for example.
The solution is to revert back to revision 10e - which you can find at:

dl.google.com/android/ndk

Extract the package and copy into the sdk/ndk-bundle directory - make sure you delete the original revision 12 first.

Comment: according to NDK bugtracker this issue has been fixed https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/8