# Detect stdint.h and C++11 on android NDK

Tags: c++, c++11, android-ndk, stdint

I found somewhere that i could detect C++11 using the following line :

```
#if __cplusplus <= 199711L
```

I'm using this to conditionally defined fixed-width types such as int32_t or uchar16_t, etc...

The problem is that when using the android NDK, `__cplusplus` is defined as `1`.
Is there a more portable way to detect C++11 and the presence of stdint.h to avoid redefinitions ?

Thank you.

Comment: You should not have to detect `stdint.h`. It should always be available because its IEEE Std 1003.1/Posix. The only header I recall having trouble with is `<sys/select.h>`. Something I needed was in it rather than `<sys/types.h>`, so I needed to conditionally include `<sys/select.h>` based on `#ifdef __ANDROID__`.

Comment: Here is the short way to solve it <p>http://stackoverflow.com/a/36324758/4242341</p>

Answer (score 1):

For me it always works:

```
$ CXX=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
$ $CXX -x c++ -E -dM /dev/null | grep __cplusplus
#define __cplusplus 199711L
$ $CXX -x c++ -std=c++11 -E -dM /dev/null | grep __cplusplus
#define __cplusplus 201103L
```

The same for LLVM toolchain:

```
$ CXX="$NDK/toolchains/llvm-3.5/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi"
$ $CXX -x c++ -E -dM /dev/null | grep __cplusplus
#define __cplusplus 199711L
$ $CXX -x c++ -std=c++11 -E -dM /dev/null | grep __cplusplus
#define __cplusplus 201103L
```

I've tried it with NDK r10d and r10e, and it works in both of them, so there is definitely something wrong with your setup. I could say more if you'd provide minimal project where such problem exist.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've decided to create a custom define to indicate whether i want things to be defined or not.