# visual studio 2015 android is missing .mk files for NDK native development

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-ndk, shared-libraries, native

I am using Visual Studio 2015 to compile and test Android native c++ code.
I really need to use `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` in `android.mk` file to use shared native library. But Visual Studio 2015 doesn't even have `.mk` files. Instead a bunch of XMLs is used.

Please help me.