# Compiling a CPP library into a DLL, can't find stdlib

Tags: android, c++, dll, haxe

Generally speaking, I'm trying to compile a CPP library into my own library as a DLL for Android (or, more accurately, an `.so` file). When my toolkit (more on this later) runs the following lines:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -Iinclude/common -Iinclude/android -std=gnu++11 --sysroot=c:\android\ndk/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -Ic:\android\ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include -Ic:\android\ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/include -DHXCPP_VISIT_ALLOCS -DHXCPP_API_LEVEL=0 -IC:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/hxcpp/3,1,39/include -Iinclude -fpic -fvisibility=hidden -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums "-D_LINUX_STDDEF_H " -Wno -psabi -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -march=armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -fomit-frame-pointer -fexceptions -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=10000 -DANDROID=ANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -O2 -DNDEBUG -c -x c++ -frtti ./common/ExternalInterface.cpp -oobj/android-v7/802265c0_ExternalInterface.obj
arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -o../ndll/Android/libopenflgpg-v7.so -frtti -nostdlib -Wl,-shared,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack --sysroot=c:\android\ndk/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -Lc:\android\ndk/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib @obj/android-v7/all_objs libs/android/libgpg-v7.a c:\android\ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a c:\android\ndk/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_so.o c:\android\ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/libgcc.a c:\android\ndk/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/libc.so c:\android\ndk/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/lib/libm.so -llog -ldl
```

I get this error (and a ton more just like it):

```
gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: libs/android/libgpg-v7.a: in function gpg::OperationQueue::Impl::StartThreadIfNotRunningLocked():turn_based_match_impl.pb.cc(.text._ZN3gpg14OperationQueue4Impl29StartThreadIfNotRunningLockedEv+0x94): error: undefined reference to 'std::__1::thread::~thread()'
```

It seems it can't find the `std` library; why not? I'm on Windows, with Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express installed, if that helps.

More specifically, I'm trying to enable the [Google Play Games C++ SDK](https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/GettingStartedNativeClient) in Haxe, by using HXCPP to compile an NDLL with all of the functions I'll be able to call using `Lib.load` in my Haxe code. The full project is [here](https://github.com/DreamShowAdventures/openfl-gpg).

I've tried including `typeinfo` and about a dozen other headers to no avail. I admit that C++ is not my strong suit, so I could be overlooking something totally obvious. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I may be completly wrong, but in std::__1::thread, the __1 remind me of errors when linking my clang++ compiled code with a g++ compiled library (boost). So maybe one of your linked libraries is expecting a thread from another std lib (e.g. libc++) than libstdc++

Comment: Okay, but how do I fix that? Or at least, test a different std lib.

Comment: I don't know exactly. One way would be to re-compile all your external lib with the same flags, but I guess it isn't very satisfying. Besides, are you sure the gcc implementation of std has std::thread available for android ?

Comment: Also, if you can, try to compile with clang++

Comment: Well I can't recompile the Google Play library because it's not open source, otherwise I would. AFAIK the only way to compile for Android via HXCPP is with `arm-linux-androideabi-g++`, but I guess I'm not sure what std lib is being used. Again, I'm not very great at C++.

Comment: It looks like the std lib is coming by way of `Ic:\android\ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi/include` but there's also `-nostdlib` which seems like it might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: These topics should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730111/how-to-use-c0x-thread-in-android-ndk and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269496/how-to-compile-c11-code-with-android-ndk-and-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Application.mk file:

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
```